# Android Marshmallow, why do I logcat error NativeCrypto cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx?

Tags: android, delphi, ssl, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

On Android Marshmallow I get this error in logcat:

```
E/NativeCrypto(16673): ssl=0x9b22e940 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x9a0c8fdc arg=0x0
```

followed by:

```
E/NativeCrypto(16673): ssl=0x9b22e940 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
```

Any idea why?

The project seems to function correctly, I just have these annoying errors in the logcat.

Comment: <stab in the dark>Is this something to do with a side effect of your app communicating across the Internet to an SSL connection or some such?</stab in the dark>

Comment: maybe i don't know yet :( but this error i have all the time when the other it's just very rarelly (but enalf to destroy my day and/or presentation) ... i continue to work on it